# Suggestions on the search filter

Tags: php, codeigniter, autocomplete, autosuggest

I am working on a website in the codeigniter framework. I am stuck at a point where I need to implement the auto complete feature. I have tried a lot but I am not able to find proper solution so far. Here is what my actual requirements are.

There is a page on website that has few search filters. When a person lands on this page all the users of the website are shown on that page. Here the real game starts. There is a filter or an input box that filters out the results on the basis of their first or last name.

Say I have a database in which i have 3 users.

Ahmad Nawaz
John Azaar
Monica Finlay

When a person starts typing "Ah" in that search box I want that the sugesstions start to appear showing him "Ahmad"... Please tell me how to do that? I have searched a lot out there but i could not find a proper answer in reference to codeignitor. this is what my code looks like at the moment...

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Persons Name" name="individual_name" id="individual_name">


<script>
$(function() {
$( "#individual_name" ).autocomplete({
source: ('autocomplete_individual_name'),
select: function () {
testing()
}
});
});
</script>
```

just under the input I wrote the script....It goes to my mentioned controller. Here is what the controller looks like...

```
$individual_name = $this->input->post('individual_name');
$where = "first_name LIKE '".$individual_name."%' OR last_name LIKE '".$individual_name."%'";
$users_array = $this->user_profile_model->findByCondition($where);
```

**First Problem**
$individual_name is not getting populated.

**Second Problem**
When I receive the results in users_array, what should I do next? How to pass it back to show suggestions??

**Third Problem**
I use to call a filter function onkeyup(). Now when a person selects through the suggestion how to call the filter?

P.S->Also kindly let me know how can i reply to the person who replies me on this question...I have used @ sign with user but it seems they dont get my reply thats why they never returned....

Any help would be highly highly appreciable...

Thanks and waiting
Ahmad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this, You may need to change the code slightly to suit you,

In your script part:

```
$("#individual_name").autocomplete({
    source         : base_url+"controller_name/suggest_names",
    minLength      : 1,
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        alert('id :'+ui.item.value) ;
        //document.location.href  = base_url+"controller_name/search?keyword="+ui.item.value; do something or redirect
    },
    success : function(resp){
        //alert("auto");
    },
    error : function(){
        alert("Oops, that didn't work. Please try again.");

    }
});
```

In your controller:

```
function suggest_names(){
    print_r ( $this->model_name->suggest_names($_REQUEST['term']) );
}
```

In your model part:

```
function suggest_names($term){
    $data   = array();
    $term   = strtolower( addslashes( trim( urldecode($term) ) ) );
    $temp   = $this->db->select('name as label, id as value')->like('name', $term, 'LEFT')->get('table_name')->result_array();
    $data   = json_encode($temp);
    //echo "<pre>";print_r($data);echo "</pre>";die;
    return $data;
}
```

Let me know if you face any problem. Hope it works for you.

Comment: workes perfectly...But i have a little problem. I used the keyup function for ajax to update the results according to the input. But  out of those suggestions that we just worked out, when you select anything with mouse, it does not update the results. That is it does not call up the function because it is called on "key up"...how to call it when a person clicks a suggestion with mouse?

Comment: You donot update on `keyup event` instead look where it alerts `alert('id :'+ui.item.value) ;`. This is the select event update here.